# Kendo grid export to PDF all pages are not showing

Tags: kendo-ui, grid

I am looking for Kendo grid export to PDF (Kendo 2016.3.914 framework ). I already implemented the below logic but the after click on Export to PDF only showing first page in PDF. Can you please check what am I missing?

```
$("#GridLogs").kendoGrid({

toolbar: ["pdf"],
pdf: {
    fileName: todayDate + "   " + "Error.pdf",
    allPages: true

},
```

Comment: Hello, can u please post all you grid configuration? Do you use virtual scrolling? According to [doc](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-pdf.allPages)
`The allPages export is not supported when virtual scrolling is enabled.`